# Render Fushion Charts in React SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, server-side-rendering

Is there any way to render fushion charts on server side in react ? . I am getting this `ReferenceError: document is not defined` error when starting the react app via express server.

Comment: Please share part of your code to see if there are issues

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here, but if you are using a charting library which relies on functionality only present on the client, for instance `window`, you could do a simple check if the component has actually mounted. There are many ways of doing this. If you are writing a functional component, you could for instance do:

```
const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsClient(true);
}, [])

return isClient ? (<SomeFusionChart/>) : (<SomePlaceHolder/>
```

within the functional component, or separate this into a custom hook.

You could also do

```
(typeof window !== 'undefined') ? (<SomeFusionChart/>) : (<SomePlaceHolder/>
```